# How to rename the "Unnamed: 0" column in csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I created a csv file from a pandas dataframe. I want to retain the `Unnamed: 0` column in the csv file but **rename** it as `class`.

```
import re
import csv

# Read the channelNames.txt file line-by-line to find the class names
channel_file = "../input_data/images/channelNames.txt"

with open(channel_file, "r") as class_info:
    lines = class_info.readlines()
    cls_names = []
    # Remove lines with "Blank"
    for l in lines:
        if re.findall(r"Blank", l):
            pass
        else:
            cls_names.append(l)

# Create classes.csv
cls_df = pd.DataFrame(cls_names, columns=["class_name"])
cls_df.to_csv('classes.csv', index=True)

cls_read = pd.read_csv("classes.csv")
cls_read.head()
```

| Unnamed: 0 | class_name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | D |

**Desired output**

| class | class_name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | D |

Answer (score 1):

```py
cls_df.to_csv('classes.csv', index=True, index_label='class')
```

If you don't have to save it with "Unnamed: 0", with this way you can save it named as "class".

P.S. columns named as "class" are a little bit dangerous; you won't be able to use `df.class`.

**Edit**
E.g.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1, 2, 3]})
df.to_csv('foo.csv', index=True, index_label='class')
pd.read_csv('foo.csv')  # outputs a column named class
```

Comment: It still returned the same column name `Unnamed: 0`

Comment: Are you sure you did it right? I added an example to my answer and it works well on me.